# Importing Java Classes in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I seem to be doing something wrong. I've built clojure from git, and am invoking it thus:

```
java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main
```

I get the repl, and then I type:

```
(import 'java.lang.string)
```

and I get:

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: java.lang.string (NO_SOURCE_FILE:1)
```

I'm trying this with lang.string since I assume it has to exist on the classpath somewhere. I've tried other libraries, all without much luck. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`String` should be capitalized, that's all.

```
user> (import 'java.lang.String)
java.lang.String
```

But everything in `java.lang` is already imported and available by default, so you shouldn't need to do this.

Answer (score 8):

Btw in non repl exercises probably the best way to include Java classes is the [ns](http://richhickey.github.com/clojure/clojure.core-api.html#clojure.core/ns) macro.

```
(ns foo.bar
  (:refer-clojure :exclude [ancestors printf])
  (:require (clojure.contrib sql sql.tests))
  (:use (my.lib this that))
  (:import (java.util Date Timer Random)
           (java.sql Connection Statement)))
```

Answer (score 2):

Bleh, I think I found it. First of all the syntax should be:

```
(import java.lang.String)
```

Also notice it's String not string.

Comment: No. The quote is necessary for import. See Brian's answer. But not for ns clauses. See Bozhidar's answer.

Comment: Actually the quote is not needed for import as well. At least in clojure 1.1, that I'm using...